# Error when running make build on remote machine

Tags: linux, python-3.5, hsm

So, I developed a python performance test to run some tests on an HSM. I am following directions to download PyKCS11, an important module I need on the remote machine. I have latest version of swig installed, and I'm trying to run a make build on the PyKCS11 folder I have downloaded in my directory on the machine. I'm getting an ungodly amount of errors when running the make build. An suggestions on what is happening with these errors?

```html
make build
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'PyKCS11._LowLevel' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fe      xceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU      _SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexce      ptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SO      URCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c       src/ck_attribute_smart.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/ck_attribute_smart      .o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fe      xceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU      _SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexce      ptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SO      URCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c       src/pkcs11lib.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pkcs11lib.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fe      xceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU      _SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexce      ptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SO      URCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c       src/pykcs11string.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pykcs11string.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fe      xceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU      _SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexce      ptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SO      URCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c       src/utility.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/utility.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fe      xceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU      _SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexce      ptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SO      URCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c       src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pykcs11_wrap.o
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:173:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:3050:4: error: #error "This python version requires swig to       be run with the '-classic' option"
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:803: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:803: error: ‘str’ was not declared in this scope
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:804: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:827: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:853: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:903: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:918: error: ‘inquiry’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:919: error: ‘intargfunc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:920: error: ‘intintargfunc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:921: error: ‘intobjargproc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:922: error: ‘intintobjargproc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:923: error: ‘getreadbufferproc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:924: error: ‘getwritebufferproc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:925: error: ‘getsegcountproc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:926: error: ‘getcharbufferproc’ does not name a type
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:927: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:927: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:927: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:927: error: initializer expression list treated as compound       expression
src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:928: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include      /c++/4.4.7/stdexcept:38,
                 from src/pykcs11_wrap.cpp:3074:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception:3      5: error: expected declaration before end of line
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build-stamp] Error 1
```

Sorry for the insanely long stack trace. Wasn't sure how to condense it so it was showing the right error messages for a possbile solution. Anyway, here's what i get when I run my python script in the remote machine.
I believe the problem to be with finding the correct compiler, but I'm not entirely sure.

Furthermore I tried to import PyKCS11 when invoking the interpreter to see a more simplified version of the error.

```
>>> import PyKCS11
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "PyKCS11/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
import PyKCS11.LowLevel
File "PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 39, in <module>
LowLevel = swig_import_helper()
File "PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
import _LowLevel
ImportError: No module named _LowLevel
```

Comment: I found a link to a possible solution regarding how to set up Python from Red Hat Enterprise Linux. [SetUp -- Python & centOS 6.4](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4) Good luck!